# Iterators VS ArrayList.addAll() with clone method in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, clone

My question is based on the assumption that the `ArrayList.addAll()` method does not make new objects but appends the same objects to the ArrayList.

Thus, in order to `addAll` objects but also have new objects then a construction must be made.

E.g., lets say that the BooClass class implements the `Cloneable` interface with deep copy and we have:

```
ArrayList<BooClass> foo1 = new ArrayList<BooClass>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) foo1.add(new BooClass());

ArrayList<BooClass> foo2 = new ArrayList<BooClass>();
```

Then, if someone wants to add all elements of `foo1` to `foo2` as **new** objects, he should do something like:

```
foo2.addAll(foo1.clone());
```

Because:

```
foo2.addAll(foo1);
```

would result in ( ? ) `foo1` and `foo2` having the same `BooClass` objects in them.

So, if the above is correct, then my question is which of the two is faster:

```
Iterator<BooClass> itBoo = foo1.iterator();
while(itBoo.hasNext()) foo2.add(itBoo.next().clone());
```

or:

```
foo2.addAll(foo1.clone());
```

?

Comment: 1. It doesn't matter. 2. If it really does matter, you can test it yourself. 3. Unless you're talking about millions of copies/clones, it doesn't matter.

Comment: So, both of them have the same complexity "degree" for the process?

Comment: Yup, they're both `O(n)`. The iterator approach is just a lot less clear.

Comment: Cool! Thnx! Because I have not ATM access to test it my self, it would really help me if I had any time measurements! :)

Comment: Actually they're not the same (well, in complexity yes, but not function). `ArrayList.clone();` does not produce a deep clone. So it's equivalent to a simple `addAll()`.

Comment: `ArrayList.clone` returns shallow copy. `foo2.addAll(foo1.clone())` has the same result as `foo2.addAll(foo1);`

Comment: @Kostas See what happens when you worry about micro-performance? You miss the things that really matter :)

Comment: @Kayaman thnx m8! Then, could you please comment/answer also on this:  The `clone()` on `foo1` will not result in calling the `clone()` of the objects in the `ArrayList`? If this is the case, then by calling `addAll()` you just add the same objects of `foo1` to `foo2`?

Comment: @Kostas That's right, while your objects may implement a deep clone, `ArrayList` doesn't. It's one of the reasons why `clone();` is a lot less useful than it seems at first glance.

Answer (score 6):

The two don't do the same thing.

```
Iterator<BooClass> itBoo = foo1.iterator();
while(itBoo.hasNext()) foo2.add(itBoo.next().clone());
```

This clones every `BooClass` object in `foo1`, and adds the clone to `foo2`.

Whereas

```
foo2.addAll(foo1.clone());
```

Clones the **list** `foo1`, resulting in a new ArrayList containing references to the same BooClass objects ass foo1, and adds all those `BooClass` objects to `foo2`.
The clone operation is completely useless, BTW, since that will have the same effect as simply doing

```
foo2.addAll(foo1);
```

If you want a deep clone, the simplest way is

```
List<BooClass> foo2 = new ArrayList<>(foo1.size());
for (BooClass boo : foo1) {
    foo2.add(boo.clone());
}
```

Note that clone() is generally considered a bad idea. You should generally prefer a copy constructor:

```
List<BooClass> foo2 = new ArrayList<>(foo1.size());
for (BooClass boo : foo1) {
    foo2.add(new BooClass(boo));
}
```

Comment: The `clone()` on `foo1` will not result in calling the `clone()` of the objects in the `ArrayList`? If this is the case, then by calling `addAll()` you just add the **same** objects of `foo1` to `foo2`?

Comment: @Kostas you got it. clone() is not recursive. This is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29): *Returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements themselves are not copied.)*

Comment: Then, would be considered a good practise to actually perform the copy construction functionality at the `clone` method?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't change the implementation of ArrayList.clone(). So you're force to explicitely create a clone of each element of the list. And the best way to do that is to avoid using clone() which is broken and badly designed, and to use a copy constructor instead.

Comment: Yeap.. I got that for the `ArrayList` class. But what about the `BooClass`? If someone wants to give to a class a copying/cloning functionality. What would be considered best? Implements the `Cloneable` interface and in the `clone()` method adds a copy construction capability or provide a `public BooClass(BooClass oldObject)` ?

Comment: The best practice is to forget about clone() and provide a copy constructor: `public BooClass(BooClass oldObject)`